# Why is my Frame subclass throwing an error in init?

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, tkinter, arguments

My program is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
class TFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, cnf, kw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    tf = TFrame(root)
    tf.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFrame.py", line 11, in <module>
    tf = TFrame(root)
  File "testFrame.py", line 7, in __init__
    Frame.__init__(self, master, cnf, kw)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

How come I'm getting a `TypeError` here? I do a similar thing like `Tkinter.Label` class.

The code for the Frame class is here:

```
`class Frame(Widget):
    """Frame widget which may contain other widgets and can have a 3D border."""
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Construct a frame widget with the parent MASTER.

        Valid resource names: background, bd, bg, borderwidth, class,
        colormap, container, cursor, height, highlightbackground,
        highlightcolor, highlightthickness, relief, takefocus, visual, width."""
        cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
        extra = ()
        if 'class_' in cnf:
            extra = ('-class', cnf['class_'])
            del cnf['class_']
        elif 'class' in cnf:
            extra = ('-class', cnf['class'])
            del cnf['class']
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unpack `kw` in the call to `Frame.__init__`.

This should work for you.

```
from Tkinter import *
class TFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    tf = TFrame(root)
    tf.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

The issue is that `Frame` is using `**kw` in its call signature, which expects a variable amount of keyword arguments, but you're trying to pass a dictionary as a positional argument.